# Macro to add text to a selected range in a Word Table

Tags: vba, excel, ms-word

I am trying to write a Macro that allows the user to select a range of cells in a Word Table to populate Column 4 with a specific text "SOLD".

[image: Word table]

Below is my VBA Macro code so far, but it only types the text in the first Column 4 (rather than the selected range of column 4's)

```
Dim iSelectionRowEnd As Integer
Dim iSelectionRowStart As Integer
Dim cl1 As Cell
Dim cl2 As Cell
Dim tbl As Table
Dim rng As Range

ActiveDocument.Bookmarks.Add Name:="MacroStartPosition", Range:=Selection.Range

If Selection.Information(wdWithInTable) = False Then
    MsgBox "Selection is not in a table."
Else

    iSelectionRowEnd = Selection.Information(wdEndOfRangeRowNumber)
    Selection.Collapse Direction:=wdCollapseStart


    iSelectionRowStart = Selection.Information(wdEndOfRangeRowNumber)

    Set tbl = Selection.Tables(1)
    Set cl1 = tbl.Cell(iSelectionRowStart, 4)
    Set cl2 = tbl.Cell(iSelectionRowEnd, 4)
    Set rng = cl1.Range.Duplicate
    rng.End = cl2.Range.End
    rng.text = ("SALE")

End If
Selection.Collapse Direction:=wdCollapseStart

If ActiveDocument.Bookmarks.Exists("MacroStartPosition") = True Then
    ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("MacroStartPosition").Select
    ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("MacroStartPosition").Delete
Else
    MsgBox "The original cursor position could not be restored."
End If

Selection.Collapse Direction:=wdCollapseStart
```

I tried to follow a similar code in Excel and apply it to Word, but I am getting errors. See below Excel.

```
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "SALE"
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("D3:D7"), Type:=xlFillDefault
Range("D3:D7").Select
```

Comment: What line fails? What is error message?

Comment: The code works, it just doesn't preform like I hope to. The Intent:  Populate ALL column 4 of selected range with "SALE".  What is does: Only populates the FIRST column 4 of the selected range.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me. Instead of `rng.text = ("SALE")` use:

```
For i = iSelectionRowStart To iSelectionRowEnd
    tbl.Cell(i, 4).Range.Text = "SALE"
Next
```

Comment: I'd like to add to my table.  In addition to "SALE", I'd like to add a sub-bullet "sales person: Jack".  I'm having difficulty determining the range to apply the bullet to:      `ListGalleries(wdBulletGallery).ListTemplates(1).Name = ""
    Selection.Range.ListFormat.ApplyListTemplateWithLevel ListTemplate:= _
        ListGalleries(wdBulletGallery).ListTemplates(1), ContinuePreviousList:= _
        False, ApplyTo:=wdListApplyToWholeList, DefaultListBehavior:= _
        wdWord10ListBehavior`

Comment: I am not having luck building a bullet list virtually in VBA. Seems must act on actual text in a paragraph selected on document. Best I can get is: `tbl.Cell(i, 1).Range.Text = "SALE" & vbCrLf & Chr(183) & " salesperson: Jack"`

Comment: I ended up "cheating" and writing a vba code to copy formatted text into that cell.  Thanks for all the help!